# php JSON decoding not working(return null while its a valid JSON)

Tags: php, json

I have JSON like this

```
{"_key":"~","emailAddress":"inezbaranowska@gmail.com","firstName":"Inez","headline":"Business Development Executive at InterContinental Geneva","id":"_qlb1a7SeS","industry":"Hospitality","lastName":"Baranowska","location":{"country":{"code":"ch"},"name":"Geneva Area, Switzerland"},"phoneNumbers":{"_total":1,"values":[{"phoneNumber":"0041 78 615 97 93","phoneType":"mobile"}]},"pictureUrl":"http://m.c.lnkd.licdn.com/mpr/mprx/0_mbFan0ZTKkCkJKytmk9gngI3tTA5Jnytui1lngMYSFLv6-w-GTcGulsslgY7kLrMVF0WYjv","positions":{"_total":1,"values":[{"company":{"id":1112438,"industry":"Hospitality","name":"InterContinental Geneva","size":"201-500 employees","type":"Sole Proprietorship"},"id":494737880,"isCurrent":true,"startDate":{"month":1,"year":2014},"title":"Business Development Executive"}]},"summary":"•\tStrong analytical, problem solving skills and capabilities to look for outside the box solutions obtained through academic achievement and internships in different industries.\n•\tExcellent communication and interpersonal abilities developed through a wide range of experiences from living and working in different countries.\n•\tSelf-confident, like to work in a challenging environment, which requires constant adjustment to new situations"}
```

When I decode it like this:

```
$linked_in=$row['linkedin_profile'];
$linkedin=json_decode($linked_in,true);
var_dump($linkedin);
```

The result is: NULL. while this code is working fine for other JSON on the same colum.

While when I'm decoding this JSON online(http://jsonformat.com) it works fine or giving result.
What is the problem with it?

Comment: [PHP json_decode](http://ie1.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) says, "This function only works with UTF-8 encoded strings."

Comment: from where u are getting `$row['linkedin_profile']`?

Comment: Try `var_dump(json_last_error())` after the failed decode.

Comment: @stg its from here $query="select id, profile, linkedin_profile from user where id=504530";
 $result=mysql_query($query);
 while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me it works too, ¿can U check the codification (maybe some character is working bad)? I'm using UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

Works for me, You sure about $row['linkedin_profile'] ? try this code:

```
$json = '{"_key":"~","emailAddress":"inezbaranowska@gmail.com","firstName":"Inez","headline":"Business Development Executive at InterContinental Geneva","id":"_qlb1a7SeS","industry":"Hospitality","lastName":"Baranowska","location":{"country":{"code":"ch"},"name":"Geneva Area, Switzerland"},"phoneNumbers":{"_total":1,"values":[{"phoneNumber":"0041 78 615 97 93","phoneType":"mobile"}]},"pictureUrl":"http://m.c.lnkd.licdn.com/mpr/mprx/0_mbFan0ZTKkCkJKytmk9gngI3tTA5Jnytui1lngMYSFLv6-w-GTcGulsslgY7kLrMVF0WYjv","positions":{"_total":1,"values":[{"company":{"id":1112438,"industry":"Hospitality","name":"InterContinental Geneva","size":"201-500 employees","type":"Sole Proprietorship"},"id":494737880,"isCurrent":true,"startDate":{"month":1,"year":2014},"title":"Business Development Executive"}]},"summary":"•\tStrong analytical, problem solving skills and capabilities to look for outside the box solutions obtained through academic achievement and internships in different industries.\n•\tExcellent communication and interpersonal abilities developed through a wide range of experiences from living and working in different countries.\n•\tSelf-confident, like to work in a challenging environment, which requires constant adjustment to new situations"}';
var_dump(json_decode($json, true));
```

Comment: when i put a copy of JSON into a variable and decode then its working but when i fetch the same from database it return NULL.

Answer (score 0):

Now its working fine

What i did-

I decode it to utf-8 before decoding the JSON like this

```
     $linked_in=$row['linkedin_profile'];

     $linked=utf8_decode($linked_in);
     $linkedin=json_decode($linked,true);
```

Comment: Note that `utf8_decode` **converts from UTF-8 to Latin-1**. If this actually solves your problem, your encoding handling is mightily screwed up. You should read [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/) and [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/).